# pdf.js console warnings (L10n)

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm using the stable version of the pdf.js viewer (2.4.456).  When loading any PDF (including the sample), I'm getting lots (~250) of console warnings from l10n.js.  Some samples are below.

The PDF displays just fine.  I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or if I can disable these logs somehow?

```
l10n.js:825 #thumbs is undefined.
l10n.js:897 #thumbs_label is undefined.
l10n.js:825 #document_outline is undefined.
l10n.js:825 #document_outline_label is undefined.
l10n.js:897 #attachments is undefined.
...
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a soltuon to this?

Comment: Unfortunately my hack solution isn't very helpful.  I just dug into viewer.js and found where these warnings are being logged.  I determined for my purposes the warnings aren't concerning, and aren't helpful, so I just commented them out.  Brute force, but worked for my situation.